# How to define a constant collection in Drools 5.6 rules

Tags: java, drools

I am using Drools 5.6. I need to deliver Rules/KnowledgeBase to another system. Some of my rules are kind of ID filters. For example, expressed in illegal syntax, it would look like:

```
rule "X":
  when
    $fact: ToBeFilteredObject(this.getId() in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...])
  then
    // do something about $fact
end
```

The "ID filter" is a collection of constants determined at the time of rule generation. Since the other system already uses Drools KB and needs some other rules from me, it would be natural and clean for me to just deliver all the filters as rules as well.

However, so far, I haven't been able to find any example for declaring such constant collections in DRL. Please consider following constraints:

1. Because the constants are determined by the rule generator, I cannot ask the client to insert global facts for such constants.
2. The filters could be huge collections containing maybe 10,000 IDs each, and 100s of thousand combined. The trick of using rules to insert them as facts in RHS would prevent us from using `StatelessKnowledgeSession`. Using `StatefulKnowledgeSession`, however, is also out of the question, since we need to execute the rule in a highly concurrent environment. We'll have to create many `StatefulKnowledgeSessions` and these collections will be duplicated among them, using huge amount of memory.

Ideally, such filers are declared like a constant in the rule definitions themselves and be kept in KB itself, so that the client can simply use `StatelessKnowledgeSession`.

Could Drools experts here explain to me if this is even doable or not?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule can be written in correct DRL syntax as

```
rule "X" // no colon here
when
  $fact: ToBeFilteredObject(id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) )
then
  // do something about $fact
end
```

Note that it is possible to refer to property `id` by its field name, even when only the getter is public.

An intelligent generator would of course process the sets of filters in a way to reduce the resulting overhead which (I suppose) would be considerable if all elements would result in a single parenthesized list. For instance, the set `(1,2,3,4,5,6, 11,12,13,14, 21,23,25)` could be expressed by the rule

```
rule "X"
when
  $fact: ToBeFilteredObject(id >= 1 && <= 6 || >= 11 && <= 14 || in (21,23,25) )
then
  // do something about $fact
end
```

Finally, a little Java would give you a powerful way for expressing arbitrarily complex filters.

```
class MyBitSet extends BitSet {
    MyBitSet( String bits ){
        super();
        // set bits according to the String value
    }
}
```

and the rule becomes

```
rule "X"
when
  ToBeFilteredObject($id:id,
            new MyBitSet("01111100000111100000010101").get($id) )
then
  // do something about $fact
end
```

If you have really many filters containing "hundreds of thousands" values there may be a better approach, based on a thorough analysis of those filters.

Finally, your assumption about stateful sessions is not correct. Sharing a rule base between several stateful sessions will not increase the memory beyond what stateless sessions will need. It is the inserted facts that will require memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apparently, your example works. And I revisited Drools documentation. It actually gave such an example for "in" operator. Silly me.